# Java FuelSDK client fails when the process is running under Executor

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, java

It seems that current version of Java FuelSDK (v 1.1.0) does not want to run in multithreaded setup with Executor.

It fails quietly with no sign of the problems or exceptions thrown.

Did anybody else experience this behaviour or is that just me?

Answer (score 0):

It was my own fault - running tests forgetting to `wait()` for the executor to finish the run.

Just in case anybody else is going to be that stupid - here is the solution...